# Join two tables in two databases in servers of different zones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A in database server 001 in DMZ zone. I have another table B in database server 002 in Internal Zone. I need to run a query that would join table A and B. However, due to our company security reason, we are not allowed to link server 001 and 002 directly. Now I have another server 003 (Just a service server, not a database server) in Internal Zone which has a SQL management studio. I think 003 can talk to both 001 and 002 because in 003 I can connect to databases on 001 and 002 by SQL SMS. But I am not able to do a join of table A and B on 003.

My SQL code is like below:

```
Select *
FROM [DATABASE001].[DBO].[tableA] AS A
INNER JOIN [DATABASE002].[DBO].[tableB] AS B
ON A.key = B.key
```

It shows error message

> Could not find server 'DATABASE001' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Is that possible to do a join of table A and table B in server 003?  Do I need to create a database in 003 and link to both 001 and 002? Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure that timezones have anything to do with this problem.

Comment: It's not a timezone thing, it's a network security thing. DMZ (demilitarized zone) is essentially the outward facing part of your network (i.e., the internet can connect to it), as against the internal part. I don't know the answer to this question though.

Comment: You can'not join tables from 2 different connections in SSMS. Join is executed by a sql server and if non of both servers is allowed to have a link  to the other one, join is impossible. Creating a database  server 003 with 2 links can be a workaround.

Comment: You need to link both the servers.  SQL Server provides the option of linking to another server. This is often used to link to other SQL Server databases.

Comment: You have an organizational issue that cannot be solved by strangers on the internet. Go talk to your manager, network admin, dba, etc. to discuss your goals and how to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks everyone's reply! Linking 003 with other two servers works for my case.